# Android studio AlertDialog ProgressBar lock

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to lock my AlertDialog. Now, when my alertDialog is enable and when i click on the screen, my alertdialog closed. I need to wait the end of the progress bar to close my alertDialog. How i can do this? Thank

Comment: `setCancelable(false);`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `alertdialog.setCancelable(false)` so the dialog does not close when the user touches elsewhere on the screen, or touches the back button on their phone.  After your progress bar completes, call `alertdialog.dismiss()` to close it.